# R - Pushing Date/time variable into SQL query with " "

Tags: mysql, r, datetime

I'm attempting to push a dynamic variable into a sql query in R so that a query increments 24 times over a 24 hour period and writes each result set to a csv. Unfortunately I'm getting this error:

```
Error in mysqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set @d2 =  2014-06-01 01:00:00 ;
```

I tried coercing my date/time using as.character thinking my date/time variable would be passed as "xx-xx-xxxx xx:xx:xx" but unfortunately everytime I run the function it drops the quotes and errors out the query. Is there some way to pass an object into a sql query in R that can be treated as date/time in MySQL?

The relevant code is as follows:

```
timeseq <- timeSequence(from = "2014-06-01", to ="2014-06-02", by = "hour")
  for (i in 1:length(timeseq)){
    if(i<length(timeseq)){
      i2 <- i+1
    }

    date1 <- timeseq[i,]
    date2 <- timeseq[i2,]
    date1 <- as.character(date1)
    date2 <- as.character(date2)

    sqlcmd <- paste("set @d1 = ", date1, ";
    set @d2 = ",date2,";

                  select 
                  ...")

    test <- dbGetQuery(MySQLcon, sqlcmd)
```

Comment: I think you need to add sigle tick marks ('...') around the dates?

Comment: When I do that SQL reads it just as date1 and date2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out on my own, but starting with the advice of Konvas. Putting single tick marks alone doesn't work because R just read my variable name as a string in the query. Instead, I had to put "'"date1"'" to get it to work.

I also had to entirely drop my defined variables at the top of my statement, R wasn't having any of that. It's fortunate that this is a simple query and I didn't really need the defined variables. My final code looks like this:

```
timeseq <- timeSequence(from = "2014-06-01", to ="2014-06-02", by = "hour")
  for (i in 1:length(timeseq)){
    if(i<length(timeseq)){
      i2 <- i+1
    }

    date1 <- timeseq[i,]
    date2 <- timeseq[i2,]
    date1 <- as.character(date1)
    date2 <- as.character(date2)

    sqlcmd <- paste("

                  select 
                  round(gps_data.latitude,2) latitude,
                  round(gps_data.longitude,2) longitude,
                  count(gps_data.id) n
                  from 
                  gps_data,
                  pims,
                  fleets
                  where
                  fleets.id = pims.fleet_id and 
                  fleets.id = 3 and
                  gps_data.pim_id = pims.id and 
                  gps_data.created_at between '",date1,"'and '",date2,"'
                  group by 1,2")

    test <- dbGetQuery(MySQLcon, sqlcmd)
    write.csv(filename=date1,x=date1)
```